# QWebview examples: only runs in specific directory

Tags: qt, qwebview

I'm trying to create a Qt app with a webview. I started out with a very simple UI with nothing more than a QWebview. When trying ui->webview->SetUrl("http://google.com"); the application crashes on something with openssl.

```
Auto configuration failed
3348:error:0200107B:system library:fopen:Unknown error:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:169:fopen('c:cygwinhomeAdministrateurbuildslavefull-windows_xp_32buildgpac_extra_libs/c:cygwinhomeAdministrateurbuildslavefull-windows_xp_32buildgpac_extra_libs/ssl/openssl.cnf','rb')
3348:error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib:.\crypto\bio\bss_file.c:174:
3348:error:0E078002:configuration file routines:DEF_LOAD:system lib:.\crypto\conf\conf_def.c:199:
```

I continues trying the examples. Domtraversal is one of the easier applications so i tried to build and run this. It works.
Changed the url to "https://gmail.com" which also works (so no ssl issues there).
When i run the debug or release .exe it works normally (qt's bin path is in my path var so there are no dll problems), but when i move the executable to say, my Desktop it does not run.
I've tried several different things:

- when i have any tree with the same amount of folders up to "build-domtraversal-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug" as the folder it is build in continues by release with the executable in it (so: c:/test/test/test/test/test/test/build-domtraversal-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug/release/app.exe) it works
- When i add folders inside the release folder (...-Debug/release/test/test/app.exe) it works
- When i change the name of either "build-domtraversal-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2010_32bit-*" or  release folders it does not work (exept for the end of the build folder name)
- When i change the name of the app itself it works.
- When i change the folder structure to D:/* it does not work
- When i turn off shadow build it does not work anymore in debug mode either. Unless i move the output .exe back into a folder structure where it did work.

There must be a path somewhere in the .pro.user or somewhere else i haven't thought about. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Cause right now I'm starting to believe in magic...

Comment: Hi! Have you resolved the issue? I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: To be frank i barely remember this, don't remember how i solved it, and can not reproduce this problem anymore. If you are still using 5.0.2 and have no reason not to I'd suggest updating to the latest Qt and testing with the browser/dom example. If that does not work let me know and I'll try to help.

Comment: I am using the latest Qt - 5.2.1. Some kind of magic is involved indeed. Yesterday it was broken, today it works fine. Since then I have just changed few minor things in the app and restarted the PC. Anyway - thanks for the response :-)

Comment: It could just have been a question of running QMake again. Forgetting that usually conjures up magical behavior.